# Android Studio: App Installs But Doesn't Open Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been trying to make an app. I've finished it with no errors, but when I install it on my device I can't open it.
I've searched for the solution on here, but nothing has helped. Most people post their AndroidManifest, so here it is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></application>

<activity android:name="Main">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: please post your logcat output

Comment: activity declaration should be inside application tags..<application><activity/></application>.